# C# equivalent of MessageBoxA(HWND_DESKTOP, msg, "Alarm", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_SETFOREGROUND);

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winforms, winapi

I am writing an alarm program in C# that displays a system modal dialog with a user-specified message at a specified time. However, I can't seem to find the C# equivalent of

```
MessageBoxA(HWND_DESKTOP, msg, "Alarm",
   MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_SETFOREGROUND);
```

**Edit:** I am trying to learn C# and the .NET libraries. I thought writing programs equivalent to some small programs that I have written in C or C++ would be a good place to start.

Comment: Is this supposed to be WinForms application?

Comment: MessageBoxA is a Windows API which you can call in C# you would just have to import the methods from the User32.dll

Comment: `MessageBox.Show()` should suffice

Comment: It is supposed to use the WinForms library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
MessageBox.Show("text", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

Find out more on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx

**EDIT:**
Just as alternative idea, this would create form of the size of your screen and show there message box by blocking everything else on the screen until you close that message box.

```
internal class TransparentWholeScreen: Form
{
    public TransparentWholeScreen()
    {
        Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
        TopMost = true;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        Shown += OnShown;
    }

    private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("text", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if(dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Just add following code on elapsing of your alarm timer:

```
    var backGroundForm = new TransparentWholeScreen();
    backGroundForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Honestly I don't like this solution, besides it won't work as alarm for people who can kill process :)

Comment: Does this show a system modal dialog that is always on top? I have already looked at that documentation and didn't find anything about system modal or always on top.

Comment: @cytpe.h when you say "*always on top*" - do you mean of your *own* application, or *all* applications? As the above code will only stay on top of the forms in your application.

Comment: On top of everything. It is an alarm program which should run in the background until it is time for the alarm to go off. Then it should appear on top of everything else until the user acknowledges it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the API you mention in the title...

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct HWND__ {

    /// int
    public int unused;
}

public partial class NativeMethods {

    /// Return Type: int
    ///hWnd: HWND->HWND__*
    ///lpText: LPCSTR->CHAR*
    ///lpCaption: LPCSTR->CHAR*
    ///uType: UINT->unsigned int
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint="MessageBoxA")]
    public static extern  int MessageBoxA([System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] System.IntPtr hWnd, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()][System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpText, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpCaption, uint uType) ;

}

public partial class NativeConstants {

    /// MB_SETFOREGROUND -> 0x00010000L
    public const int MB_SETFOREGROUND = 65536;

    /// MB_SYSTEMMODAL -> 0x00001000L
    public const int MB_SYSTEMMODAL = 4096;

    /// MB_ICONWARNING -> MB_ICONEXCLAMATION
    public const int MB_ICONWARNING = NativeConstants.MB_ICONEXCLAMATION;

    /// MB_OK -> 0x00000000L
    public const int MB_OK = 0;

    /// MB_ICONEXCLAMATION -> 0x00000030L
    public const int MB_ICONEXCLAMATION = 48;
}
```

Comment: I used the WinAPI function in C and C++. However, I am looking for the WinForms equivalent, as I am trying to learn C# and the .NET library. I thought writing programs equivalent to some small programs I have written in C or C++ would be a good place to start. Nevertheless, it is interesting to see how WinAPI functions can be used in C# since I can't `#include <Windows.h>`.

Comment: There are not necessarily exact equivalents to all WinAPI functions. Although the .Net Framework is very extensive and covers much of the WinAPI. This is part of the reason that the PInvoke concept is present. The other reason is to allow using modules written in other programming languages.

Comment: To make determining the correct declarations easy see...

http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop

Comment: I'm somewhat suprised that the BCL doesn't expose MB_SETFOREGROUND in the enum.